# How to modify this logic for checking the user credentials in a database and then in Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an intranet web-based application that stores the information of added users in its database.

What I want to do is the following: when the user browses to the webstie, it will check if the user exists in its own database or not. If not, it is going to check his information using Active Directory.

I wrote the method but the problem after checking the database and if the user is not there, it will go to the second method which is checking the organization code of the employee:

```
public static bool isMember(string userid)
{
        Employee employee = new Employee(userid);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userid))
        {
            string username = userid;
            string connString = "Data Source=appServer\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=dbTest;Integrated Security=True";
            string cmdText2 = "SELECT Count(*) FROM employee WHERE Username = @username";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                // Open DB connection.
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText2, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = username;
                    var count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    return count == 1; // return true if there's only one employee with given name
                }
            }
        }
        else if (employee.department.Code == "30003143") //The SapCode of department is "30003143"
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

So how to fix that? How to make the application goes through (else if) clause if the user does not exist in the database?

Comment: Why do you do that at all? You already have a user database: Active Direcotry. Have you webapp perform Windows (SPNEGO) authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy:

```
public static bool isMember(string userid)
{
    // guard clause - if "userid" is invalid, return "false" right away 
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userid))
    {
        return false
    }

    //Object from Employee class
    Employee employee = new Employee(userid);

    string username = userid;
    string connString = "Data Source=appServer\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=dbTest;Integrated Security=True";
    string cmdText2 = "SELECT Count(*) FROM employee WHERE Username = @username";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText2, conn))
    {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = username;

            conn.Open();

            var count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (count == 1)
            {
               return true; // return true if there's only one employee with given name
            }
    }

    // if the user already existed in the database - then the above RETURN has 
    // returned "true" to the caller. So these lines are **only** executed if the
    // user was NOT found in the database.

    if (employee.department.Code == "30003143") //The SapCode of department is "30003143"
        return true;

    // now check in Active Directory here.....     
    return UserExistsInActiveDirectory();
}
```